# Use android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase in Java Library module

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a project in android-studio which contains two modules:

```
+app
--+src
+library
--+src
--+test
```

`app` is a Android Application Module and `library` is a Java Library Module. The idea is that `app` contains the android gui and `library` contains the program logic. I made `library` a Java Library Module to be able to use JUnit 4.

The problem is that I need a SQLite database connection but I can't import android packages in `library`. How do I solve that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to resolve this dependency, nor does it make sense to have `SQLiteDatabase` (an Android-specific class) appear in anything other than an Android library/module.

You can write functional JUnit tests by extending [`TestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestCase.html) or [`AndroidTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html) and including this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="your.package.name" />
```

More information here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#JUnit

Comment: But android ships with Junit 3 and I use Junit 4 for unit test the library. Then I'll move the database class to `app` or create an additional android library.